# Sending data to a Wildfly 10 embedded Artemis instance and receive them back USING Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to send some data to Wildfly 10 Artemis instance and receive them back using Apache Camel.
Here, I know that, this can be done using camel-jms component.

In this case first I created a simple example to check whether this is working fine or not.
But it gives below exception at the ConnectionFactory creating point.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://localhost:8080]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.failOverSequence(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:213)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingStore(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:144)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.namingOperation(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:125)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.HaRemoteNamingStore.lookup(HaRemoteNamingStore.java:241)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:79)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.RemoteContext.lookup(RemoteContext.java:83)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
```

**Implementation :**

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, WILDFLY_REMOTING_URL);
props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, JMS_USERNAME);
props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, JMS_PASSWORD);

InitialContext context = new InitialContext(props); 
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =  (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup(JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI);
System.out.println("connectionFactory : " + connectionFactory);

SimpleRouteBuilder routeBuilder = new SimpleRouteBuilder();
CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
ctx.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

ctx.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
ctx.start();
Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
ctx.stop();
```

**Constants :**

```
public final static String JMS_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI="jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
public final static String JMS_QUEUE_JNDI="jms/queue/TestQ";
public final static String JMS_USERNAME="jmsuser";       //  The role for this user is "guest" in ApplicationRealm
public final static String JMS_PASSWORD="jmsuser@123";  
public final static String WILDFLY_REMOTING_URL="http-remoting://localhost:8080";
```

**Imports :**

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
```

But this happens successefully when I'm using pure javax.jms (not through Camel) as mentioned in [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=2739). And it works successfully when I send messages to active mq diretly (not to Wildfly Artemis).

```
SimpleRouteBuilder routeBuilder = new SimpleRouteBuilder();
CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://0.0.0.0:61616");
ctx.addComponent("jms", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

ctx.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
ctx.start();
Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 1000);
ctx.stop();
```

What I want to know is Sending data to a Wildfly embedded Artemis insnatnce and receive them back **USING Apache Camel**.
Can anybody give a little tip on this?

Answer (score 2):

The error you're receiving is:

```
Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://localhost:8080]
```

This indicates to me that your Wildfly instance is not actually listening on localhost:8080 for JNDI connections.  You haven't included any Wildfly configuration or logging so this is only a guess.

Also you said that, "it works successfully when I send messages to active mq diretly (not to Wildfly Artemis)," but it's not clear what this actually means.  Apache ActiveMQ Artemis is (as the name suggests) an ActiveMQ broker so when you say you sent messages to "active mq" it's not clear whether you mean standalone Artemis (i.e. not embedded in Wildfly) or the ActiveMQ 5.x broker.

Lastly, calling Artemis "Wildfly Artemis" can be a bit misleading since Artemis is not a Wildfly project but an Apache one.  I assume by "Wildfly Artemis" you really mean "ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in Wildfly."

Comment: @ Justin, Thank you for the answer. And sorry for the unclear areas in my question. In this case, by mentioning  "active mq diretly" means sending to the standalone ActiveMQ 5.x broker. And Yes by mentioning Wildfly Artemis I meaned ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in Wildfly.